# not showing complete result of my sql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

i make lottery website
and in this i have result page

everything works fine
but i have a problem when i click on results
the results page was show only 10 Results not showing complete result
i have in mysql database 15 Results
but on websites its showing 10 Results only

here is php file code

```
        <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2 class="heading-title">Draw Results</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-responsive" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">LOTTERY</th>
                    <th scope="col">TICKET</th>
                    <th scope="col">MATCH</th>
                    <th scope="col">AMOUNT</th>
                    <th scope="col">DRAW</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($results as $res)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $res->lot->title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $res->ticket }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $res->mat }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $res->amount }} {{ $gnl->cur }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $res->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you fetch data from database.

Comment: show screenshot of your table also

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your code for fetching data is correct then check if datatable is applied by default or not.

Comment: You should mention this sentence in comment section.